# 2D array - How to remove duplicate values but keep the sub arrays separated

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, filter, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from my 2d array but I need to keep sub-arrays separately.

Arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
c = [3,4,5,6]
d = [4,5,6,7]

newarray = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]]
```

want to get the following result:

```
newarraynoduplicates = [[1,2,3,4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

I have tried the following things

```
[a|b|c|d] => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
[a|b|c|d] =>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

also tried

```
newarray.uniq! => nil!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most generic approach would be:

```
[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]].
  each_with_object([]) { |a, acc| acc << a - acc.flatten } 
#⇒ [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

or

```
[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]].
  reduce([]) { |acc, a| acc << a - acc.flatten }
#⇒ [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

Comment: mudsie, you've made the implicit assumption that `arr.first` contains no duplicates. While the OP's example contains no duplicates, the specification is mute about that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland true that. `reduce(arr.pop.uniq) { ... } ` would fix the issue.

Comment: `unshift`, of course. Correct version: `arr.dup.tap { |a| break a.reduce(a.unshift.uniq) { |acc, e| acc << e - acc.flatten } }`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for:

```
new_array = [a, b - a, c - b - a, d - c - b - a ]
#=> [[1,2,3,4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

Comment: What if we have `1_000` arrays? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'

def doit(arr)
  s = Set.new
  arr.map { |a| a.select { |e| s.add?(e) } }
end
```

```
doit [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]]
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]] 
doit [[1,2,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5,3], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]]
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

See [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F). This should be quite efficient as set lookups are very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I did not make many tests, but is seems to work:

```
newarray = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]]

newarray.map.with_index { |e, i| (e - newarray.reverse[newarray.size - i..].flatten).uniq }
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

Or, to avoid reversing at each loop:

```
newarray.reverse.then{ |ary| newarray.map.with_index { |e, i| (e - ary[newarray.size - i..].flatten).uniq } }
```